# sql server confusing Histogram

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, histogram, database-administration

I have a question on histogram want to know how does it work internally,

```
RANGE_HI_KEY | RANGE_ROWS | EQ_ROWS | DISTINCT_RANGE_ROWS | AVG_RANGE_ROWS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
10005138     |     6055   | 137     | 330                 | 18.34848
10007165     |     3262   | 212     | 95                  | 34.33684
```

please help from above histogram how QO it calculate "ESTIMATED ROWS" from below range

`col >10005139 and 
col <10005300`

Comment: I've edited to make the table readable. But below the table looks like it needs a bit of editing still - are there meant to be two different scenarios you're asking about? Because at the moment, the two look identical.

Comment: This isn't documented. What estimated rows are you seeing? We might be able to figure out the formula from that (though I'm not massively hopeful. I [looked at this for `BETWEEN` before](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55194/weird-sql-server-instance-crash-on-casting-to-numeric/55243#55243) and couldn't see an obvious formula)

Comment: thanx  Damien_The_Unbeliever for editing the formatting, ops i just type question twice just to get quick response(my mistake), hey martin i am seeing  222.815 as estimation.